# upload the file into the server using ftp in php

Tags: php, android, ftp, server

i have tried to upload the image into the server but i could not have the permission to access the folder so i have used the FTP connection. Through the android app i have encode the image and sent it to the server. In the server side, i just decode it and tried to upload it. But i could not able to upload it. Can you please help me on this.

```
 <?php
     // Get image string posted from Android App
     $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     // Get file name posted from Android App
     $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
     // Decode Image
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
     header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $ftp_server = "";
    $ftp_user_name = "";
    $ftp_user_pass = "";
    $destination_file = "/upload/images/".time().jpg";


    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name,$conn_id";
    }

    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file,  $binary, FTP_BINARY);

    if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed! $upload";
    } else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, I got the following issue,\n <br/><b>Warning</b>:ftp_put(PNG)[<a href='function.ftp-put'</a>]:failed to open stream:Invalid argument in .php file

Answer (score 0):

The third param of the function [ftp_put](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) expects a filename. You are passing the image binary as a string.

Change tis line:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file,  $binary, FTP_BINARY);
```

To:

```
$fileName = uniqid().'.jpg';
$filePath = '/tmp/'.$uniqid;
file_put_contents($filePath, $binary);

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file,  $filePath, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Hi, I have faced the following issue <br/><b>warning</b>:file_put_contents(/tmp/)[<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]:failed to open stream:invalid argument.

Comment: Does the directory /tmp exist on your system?

Comment: sorry, i don't have a server credential.just i have the FTP credential alone,so i don't know whether /tmp exists or not and   I have tried with the $filePath =getcwd().$uniqid; but it reports, permission denied issue on file_put_contents();.  (i don't have a permission to write on the folder so that i am using FTP)

Comment: You should probably fix that permission problem first. Then you can also bypass that ugly solution to upload the file again via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

please add ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); after successful login. Then only this will work.